# Creating javafx Image from data array

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm programming an image processing application, using javafx for the gui und I want to show the processed picture on screen. My programm is handling the image as a three dimensional double array like double[3][1080][1920] so I have to reduce the colorspace of the image and convert the doubles to byte or (if possible) shorts, because the ImageView of javafx doesn't support floating point values or 64 bit for each of the RGB components. I found out, that Imageview can only load data from a file or an inputstream, so I have to create a BufferedImage, fill it with the convertet data from the array and write the BufferedImage encodet as JPEG, BMP, PNG or GIF to a stream and read this stream with the construcor of a javafx.scene.image.Image and pass this image to the ImageView. A cruel way to convert an array to an image, I newer wanted to be encoded in any file format, but I found no alternative ti this (except of not using javafx).
Now my first question:
The setRGB method of BufferedImage takes all color components stuck together as int. How can I combine them in the correct way?
And my second question:

Is the andy way to save more than 8 bit for each component?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's no need to go via a file format. You can create an `ImageView` and set the `Image` directly with `setImage(...)`. Use a [`WritableImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) and its [`PixelWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) to put the data into the image.

Comment: Using the `WritableImage` I can not only avoid conversions, I can use `setPixels` with `PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance` to handle to data as a `byte` array. That helped a lot.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WritableImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) provides an [`PixelFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.html) handling an `byte` array in exactly that way, using [`PixelWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html)'s [`setPixels`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html#setPixels-int-int-int-int-javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat-byte:A-int-int-) with the [`PixelFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.html) set to [`PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.html#getByteRgbInstance--).